# Can I simulate traits/mixins in Swift?

Tags: swift, mixins, traits

Does Swift have a way of mixing in traits, a la Scala? The section of the Swift book on using extensions to add protocols to existing classes comes tantalizingly close. However, since protocols can't contain an implementation, this can't be used to mix code into a class. Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Swift 2.0, yes!

[Providing Default Implementations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)

> You can use protocol extensions to provide a default implementation
>   to any method or property requirement of that protocol. If a
>   conforming type provides its own implementation of a required method
>   or property, that implementation will be used instead of the one
>   provided by the extension.

Comment: After looking a little closer, I think protocol extensions implement mixins, rather than traits, since it doesn't seem possible to have multiple chained method implementations in protocol extensions.

Comment: I don't understand what that means, and would like to. I thought that "mixin" meant inheriting implementations from multiple protocols.

Comment: Mixins are like Ruby's modules (and Swift's protocol extensions) - you simply mix methods from one module into a class. Traits (as in Scala) are more powerful - you can mix several traits into one class and they affect the overall inheritance chain. If I have three traits mixed into a class with a method (say, "didLoadView"), if I call "super.loadView" in that class, it will call that method in one of the traits, which can potentially call that method in the next trait. Traits offer a restricted variety of multiple inheritance. https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html

Comment: If you have the time, answering this yourself, and providing clarification on how this is different than (self as Protocol).method, would probably be the most useful to others.

Comment: Tell me how? Agree with Jessy.

Comment: @jtianling Like I said, mixins simply let you bring a bunch of method implementations and abstract methods into a class. Traits are more complex. Their functionality is a superset of mixins - traits can inherit from other traits and call methods in their superclass. They're like lightweight objects, except that they can't be instantiated directly. They can only be subclassed by real classes. The best intro I know if is the artima.com link I included in my comment above.

Comment: The properties you describe are present in Swift 2.0's protocols; "self as X" is used instead of "super".

Comment: Confused, I meant that the Default Implementations in Swift 2.0 can't simulate the mixins.

Comment: Default implementations for me still doesn't present a "Yes" answer to the question, because the answer to "Does Swift have a way of mixing in traits, a la Scala?" even in Swift 2.0 is NO.

Comment: What's missing? I don't know Scala, but the main limitation I can think of is lack of stored properties, which is gotten around by using private dictionaries for hashables.

Answer (score 9):

One way to simulate mixing is use generic function to provide implementation

For example with these protocols

```
protocol Named {
    func GetName() -> String
}

protocol NamedExtension {
    func GetLowercaseName() -> String
    func GetUppercaseName() -> String
}
```

I want some class to implement `GetName()` and use mixing so they also get `GetLowercaseName()` and  `GetUppercaseName()` without implement them

This is the implementation of `NamedExtension` as in free function

```
func GetLowercaseNameImpl<T:Named>(obj:T) -> String {
    return obj.GetName().lowercaseString
}

func GetUppercaseNameImpl<T:Named>(obj:T) -> String {
    return obj.GetName().uppercaseString
}
```

and extensions on `Int`

```
extension Int : Named {
    func GetName() -> String {
        return "Int"
    }
}

extension Int : NamedExtension {
    // use provided implementation
    func GetLowercaseName() -> String {
        return GetLowercaseNameImpl(self)
    }
    func GetUppercaseName() -> String {
        return GetUppercaseNameImpl(self)
    }
}
```

and I can use

```
1.GetName() // result Int
1.GetUppercaseName() // result "INT"
1.GetLowercaseName() // result "int"
```

Comment: I know it is not ideal because there are still 8 lines of boilerplate code here, hopefully there are better ways

Comment: Just to update this answer for Swift 2, the boilerplate pretty much goes away with protocol extensions: https://gist.github.com/abbottmg/1d6df49826cbf6233148

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Scala, but from what you're telling me it is possible to simultaneously create a `protocol` and an `extension` that extends a type to add "pseudo-trait" behavior.

For example:

```
protocol IsGreaterThan
{
    func isGreaterThan(other:Int) -> Bool
    func isNotGreaterThan(other:Int) -> Bool
}

extension Int : IsGreaterThan
{
    func isGreaterThan(other:Int) -> Bool
    {
        return self > other
    }

    func isNotGreaterThan(other:Int) -> Bool
    {
        return !isGreaterThan(other)
    }
}
```

The real hamstring is how generics are somewhat limited for now. I think they will improve a lot in the coming revisions of Swift.

Comment: immediately this is where my brain went, would love to see the other options, i suspect there are more ways than these 2

Comment: The key feature traits/mixins have over protocols is that they can include method implementations and can be mixed into other classes. It doesn't seem like this is quite possible in Swift today.

Comment: @bill I don't understand what the issue is. Extensions can add method implementations and it can add protocols.

Comment: @sanz Yes, but you have to rewrite the implementations for any class you extend. A trait system (or something approximating it) would let me have one class called `IntegerComparable` that includes implementation and can simply be mixed into other classes. Under your system, I would need to copy the method bodies `isGreaterThan` and `isNotGreaterThan` into every class I want to extend, right?

Comment: @Bill Yes, you are correct, unfortunately you would have to do so.

Comment: Well you could just use functions instead of methods, that expect a parameter conforming to the protocol. That way you only have to write it once and get the same behavior as traits.

Comment: @Bill The key feature traits have over protocols is actually the fact that traits can introduce stored properties to the classes they are mixed into. As of Swift 2.0 default implementations are supported but stored properties are still not available.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Bryan Chen's answer:

```
import Foundation

protocol Named {
    var name : String { get }
}

protocol NamedExtension : Named { // NB extends Named
    var lowercaseName : String { get }
    var uppercaseName : String { get }
}

struct NamedExtensionDefault { // Put defaults inside a struct to keep name spaces seperate
    static func lowercaseName(named : NamedExtension) -> String {
        return (named.name as NSString).lowercaseString
    }
    static func uppercaseName(named : NamedExtension) -> String {
        return (named.name as NSString).uppercaseString
    }
}

extension Int : NamedExtension {
    var name : String {
    return "Int"
    }
    // Use default implementation
    var lowercaseName : String {
    return NamedExtensionDefault.lowercaseName(self)
    }
    var uppercaseName : String {
    return NamedExtensionDefault.uppercaseName(self)
    }
}

1.name // result Int
1.uppercaseName // result "INT"
1.lowercaseName // result "int"
```

The main difference from Bryan's answer is that I didn't use generics because I made `NamedExtension` extends `Named`, so that the default implementations can access `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my (not yet widely tested) way of doing what I think are Scala traits in Swift 2.1.1, Playgrounds-ready, two versions:

Less flexible:

```
protocol BigBadProtocol {
    func madFunc() -> String;
    // func otherFunc();
    // Maybe a couple more functions here.
}

protocol BlueMadFuncUser: BigBadProtocol {}

extension BlueMadFuncUser {
    func madFunc() -> String {
        return "Blue"
    }
}

protocol RedMadFuncUser: BigBadProtocol {}

extension RedMadFuncUser {
    func madFunc() -> String {
        return "Red"
    }
}

class ClearClass: BigBadProtocol {
    func madFunc() -> String {
        return "Clear"
    }
}

class BlueClass: BlueMadFuncUser {}

class RedClass: RedMadFuncUser {}
```

More flexible:

```
protocol BigBadProtocol {
    func madFunc() -> String;
    // func otherFunc();
    // Maybe a couple more functions here.
}

protocol BlueMadFuncUser {}

extension BigBadProtocol where Self: BlueMadFuncUser {
    func madFunc() -> String {
        return "Blue"
    }
}

protocol RedMadFuncUser {}

extension BigBadProtocol where Self: RedMadFuncUser {
    func madFunc() -> String {
        return "Red"
    }
}

class ClearClass: BigBadProtocol {
    func madFunc() -> String {
        return "Clear"
    }
}

class BlueClass: BigBadProtocol, BlueMadFuncUser {}

class RedClass: BigBadProtocol, RedMadFuncUser {}
```

Sanity check:

```
var classes: [BigBadProtocol] = [ClearClass(), BlueClass(), RedClass()]

// Prints "Clear, Blue, Red\n"
print((classes.map { $0.madFunc() }).joinWithSeparator(", "))

// Print another way for Playgrounds, which appears to bug out on the lines above
var s = ""
for klass in classes {
    s += klass.madFunc() + " "
}
print(s)
```

BlueMadFuncUser and RedMadFuncUser are two versions of a trait. My terminology might be off, but then you can independently create a second trait like that and mix and match in your classes as you please.

Would be much more challenging or boiler-plate-y to reuse logic like that with an inheritance-based approach.

I ended up wanting this pattern after finding it very useful in Hack for PHP, where from what I can tell traits are very similar to Scala's: https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/other-features/trait-and-interface-requirements)